# Mysql having a lot of "query end" state and becoming slow

Tags: mysql, processlist

This happen to me in my Master DB. Due to too many "query end" it becoming slow.
What is possible problem and how to solve this?[image]

Below is my cnf

```html
#Custom
max_connections=500
max_connect_errors=99999

expire_logs_days = 2
max_binlog_size  = 1G

#Replication purpose
server-id=1
binlog-do-db=pencilm_running
binlog-format = mixed
log-bin=mysql-bin
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=0

#Performance issue
thread_cache_size=30
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=1M

slow_query_log=1


group_concat_max_len = 5000
#join_buffer_size = 250000
```

Comment: The query cache limit seems excessive; possibly unrelated, but I'd reduce it to 32M.  But take a look at the output from `iostat -x 1` for the disks used by MySQL. Check the impact of setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` which can be changed without a restart using `SET GLOBAL ...`.

Comment: After implementing yr thought, immidiately all the query end gone. And runs smooth faster. TQ @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: @JoeIjam I am facing a similar issue. I am using aws rds mysql. I am a bit worried of making changes that might affect the db. When I check innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit on my parameter group, it is not set. Can you tell me what changes you made to fix your issue?